# Concurrency in nested for loop

Tags: loops, go, concurrency

I'm trying to do some image analysis, and am analyzing each pixel in a Goroutine. My code currently looks like this:

```golang
func FindEdgesV2(img image.Image) PointSet {
    res := make(PointSet)
    c := make(chan Point)
    bounds := img.Bounds()
    width, height := bounds.Max.X, bounds.Max.Y

    size := width*height - width*2 - height*2 + 4
    px := 0
    bar := CreateBar(size, "reading pixels...")
    for y := 1; y < height-1; y++ {
        for x := 1; x < width-1; x++ {

            go func(x, y int, c chan Point) {
                gradient := [3][3]int{}
                for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
                    for j := 0; j < 3; j++ {
                        gradient[i][j] = int(Luminance(img.At(x-1+i, y-1+i)))
                    }
                }

                gx, gy := 0, 0
                for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
                    for j := 0; j < 3; j++ {
                        gx += gradient[i][j] * horizontal[i][j]
                        gy += gradient[i][j] * vertical[i][j]
                    }
                }
                colorCode := int(math.Sqrt(float64(gx*gx + gy*gy)))
                if colorCode > 80 {
                    c <- Point{x, y}
                }
            }(x, y, c)

            px++
            bar.Set(px)
        }
    }
    for p := range c {
        res[p] = true
    }
    return res
}
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

I'm simply trying to write to a channel using multiple Goroutines, and then put the contents of that channel into a map. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should close the channel when all goroutines are done. To do that, you first have to detect when all goroutines are done using a WaitGroup:

```
...
bar := CreateBar(size, "reading pixels...")
wg:=sync.WaitGroup{}
for y := 1; y < height-1; y++ {
   for x := 1; x < width-1; x++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(x, y int, c chan Point) {
           defer wg.Done()
           ...
```

Then close the channel when all gorotines are done:

```
go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(c)
}()
for p := range c {
    res[p] = true
}
```